# Erase portion from UIBezierpath

Tags: uibezierpath, erase, stroke

I have drawn some line using UIBezierpath.
Now I wanted to erase some portion of that line.
How can I erase any specific area of a line drawn by UIBezierpath

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove part of UIBezierPath.

Remove old path:
`oldPath = nil` which clears the old bezier path! and call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view where you draw.

Create new UIBezierPath without that part. 
And set new path.

Comment: This gives me the error "Nil cannot be assigned to type 'UIBezierPath'"